# Kafka String Message is throwing Exception when sending a message with key='null'

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send String message using Kafka, its throwing Exception with Key of the message being null. But as far as I know the key is automatically assigned by Kafka.

I am getting this error in my console.

```
2021-02-23 14:34:10.420 ERROR 36996 --- [ad | producer-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='"Now is the time for all." ' to topic my_topic:
```

and the following also.

I suspect I am not being able to run Kafka properly.

I running Kafka and zookeeper using docker-compose.

Here is my application.properties file content.

```
kafka.bootstrapAddress=localhost:9092
message.topic.name=my_topic
```

Here is the content of my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3'
services:
 zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  container_name: zookeeper
  restart: always
  logging:
   driver: json-file
   options:
     max-size: 1m
     max-file: '5'
  ports:
  - "2181:2181"

 kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  container_name: kafka
  restart: always
  ports:
   - "9092:9092"
  depends_on:
   - zookeeper
  links:
   - zookeeper:zookeeper
  logging:
   driver: json-file
   options:
     max-size: 1m
     max-file: '5'
  environment :
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "my_topic:2:1"
```

This is my Service class for Producer.

```
@Service
public class KafkaProducer {
    
    private static final String TOPIC= "my_topic";
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> stringObjectKafkaTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, EntryObject> entryObjectKafkaTemplate;
    
    public void writeStringMessage(String strMessage) {
        this.stringObjectKafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, strMessage);
    }
    
    public void writeMessage(EntryObject entryMsg) {
        this.entryObjectKafkaTemplate.send(TOPIC, entryMsg);
    }

}
```

And here is my configuration for the KafkaProducers.

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> stringProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(stringProducerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, EntryObject> entryObjectProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, EntryObject> entryObjectKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(entryObjectProducerFactory());
    }
}
```

And when I am running the **docker-compose up** I am getting the following logs from Kafka. I suspect the Kafka is not configured properly.

[image: docker-compose logs when running the Kafka]

Any help and guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show the full exception

Comment: Is the problem fixed? If so please provide the solution.